# I don't want to get out of my application when update the password on firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Iam programming on backend side, when i update the password on firebase my app logout

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email).then(user => {
      const { uid } = user
        admin.auth().updateUser(uid,{
          password,
        })
```

I don't want to get out of my application.
when I edit my password, I think the TOKENS are destroyed and my application rejects me, my user goes out of the application

I just want to update my password I don't want to quit the application

i should change the password from backend as well?, actually i am using firebase admin

**I must change from my backend or enough from the frontend?**

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to get out of my application"? Please edit the question to be more clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the password change feature in my code using firebase authentication.
According to firebase docs, you need to reauthenticate the current user before changing the password.
So try implementing that, because in my case it does not log me out of my application after changing password.
Here you can get the current user password by providing email and current password.

```
 var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email,
        current_password
    );
```

After that, you can reauthenticate the user and update the password as I am doing here.

```
user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential).then( data => {
     // User re-authenticated.
      user.updatePassword(newpassword)
        .then(() => {
            //Password successfully updated
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            //Failed to update password
         });
 }).catch((error) => {
     //An error happened.
     //Failed to reauthenticate user
 });
```

See this for reference -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#set_a_users_password

Comment: i am using nodejs, so i am using firebase sdk

Comment: i should change the password from backend as well?

Comment: I am also using the firebase admin. Have you tried my solution? From where you are updating the password?

Comment: are you using firebase sdk?  i am using firebase sdk

Comment: yes on frontend side your code run very well, but shouldn't I use this?https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=es

Comment: ok, then I think changing the password on the backend side will make your existing token invalid, and you have to login again. That's correct behavior for security considerations.

Comment: my doubt is that, I can change the password from frontend and I shouldn't change it from backend anymore, right?

Comment: yes, right! maybe you can change it from backend as well but that does not fit in your requirement. So you should change it form frontend only.